# What does an overwrite flag indicate in an install log?

Tags: logging, windows-installer, registry, nmap, winpcap

I want to understand the contents of install log for npcap and what the contents mean:

Call, Jump, Overwrite, File, WriteRegStr, WriteRegDWORD, allowskipfilesflag, RMDir.

Comment: Not sure what technology that installer is based on, what does the installer dialog look like? Just the first one.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul CreateDirectory: "C:\Program Files\Npcap" created
File: overwriteflag=0, allowskipfilesflag=2, name="LICENSE" #Please let me know if this helps#